# Why does accessing elements from a list in generated with .apply() return IndexError for indexes that fall within the len of the list?

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

Given a table with data like the the following, the column ['ordered_stint'] is a string. I am able to access parts of that string using `stints['ordered_stint].split(', ')`.

```
|id       |ordered_stint                                              |
|---------|-----------------------------------------------------------|
|12345678 | 1234, 5678, 9012, 3456, 7891, 2345, 6789, 1235, 6781, 2468|
|24682468 | 1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888, 9999, 3579|
```

I'd like to split this string into its 10 substrings, with each substring going to a separate column. Running the following loop (independently of the DataFrame) I am able to access any value in the string:

```
for s in stints['ordered_stint']:
    j = [i for i in s.split(', ')]
    print(j[0])
```

Indeed, I can even run as follows and confirm that the `len` of j (the generated list) is 10, and then access any index between 0 and 9.

```
for s in stints['ordered_stint']:
    j = [i for i in s.split(', ')]
    print(len(j))
    print(j[1])
```

When I attempt to perform the same operation in the context of the DataFrame, however, I consistently raise `IndexError: List index out of range` for any index above 0. So in the following snippet, ['offense_1'] produces the first element in ['ordered_stint'], but ['offense_2'] raises IndexError:

```
def stint_slicer(x,num):
    j = [i for i in x.split(', ')]
    return j[num]

stints['offense_1'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,0))
stints['offense_2'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,1))
```

Full traceback is below. Note that I have tried using both .map() and .apply(), with the same exception raised in either case. I have also tried using .apply() without a lambda, as follows:

`stints['offense_1'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(stint_slicer(x,0))`

This raises AttributeError: {value in the list} is not a valid function for 'Series' object, as this would be applying the function to the entire Series, rather than applying it elementwise.

```
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-299-8868e08ecc4a> in <module>
     24 
     25 stints['offense_1'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,0))
---> 26 stints['offense_2'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,1))
     27 #stints['offense_3'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,2))
     28 #stints['offense_4'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,3))

~\Miniconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   4198             else:
   4199                 values = self.astype(object)._values
-> 4200                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, convert=convert_dtype)
   4201 
   4202         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas\_libs\lib.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-299-8868e08ecc4a> in <lambda>(x)
     24 
     25 stints['offense_1'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,0))
---> 26 stints['offense_2'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,1))
     27 #stints['offense_3'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,2))
     28 #stints['offense_4'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,3))

<ipython-input-299-8868e08ecc4a> in stint_slicer(x, num)
     21 def stint_slicer(x,num):
     22     j = [i for i in x.split(', ')]
---> 23     return j[num]
     24 
     25 stints['offense_1'] = stints['ordered_stint'].apply(lambda x: stint_slicer(x,0))

IndexError: list index out of range
```

Comment: Your "sample provided" link seems to require a login. You should include a sample of the data *in the question*, rather than providing a link.

Comment: Updated per request

Answer (score 0):

Based on your requirements, that should work:

```
>>> data={'id': {0: 12345678, 1: 24682468},
     ...:  'ordered_stint': {0: '1234, 5678, 9012, 3456, 7891, 2345, 6789, 1235, 6781, 2468',
     ...:   1: '1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888, 9999, 3579'}}

>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data)

         id                                      ordered_stint
0  12345678  1234, 5678, 9012, 3456, 7891, 2345, 6789, 1235...
1  24682468  1111, 2222, 3333, 4444, 5555, 6666, 7777, 8888...

>>> df.ordered_stint = df.ordered_stint.str.split(',')
>>> pd.concat([df.id, pd.DataFrame(df.ordered_stint.to_list())], axis=1)
         id     0      1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8      9
0  12345678  1234   5678   9012   3456   7891   2345   6789   1235   6781   2468
1  24682468  1111   2222   3333   4444   5555   6666   7777   8888   9999   3579
```